# Is a Muslim man permitted to marry a Christian woman who does not want to accept Islam?

Tags: nikah, non-muslim

Is a Muslim man permitted to marry a Christian woman who does not want to accept Islam?

I agree that it should be avoided, but is it permitted?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is allowed. Allah says in the Qu'ran:

> “Made lawful to you this day are At‑Tayyibaat [all kinds of Halaal (lawful) foods, which Allaah has made lawful (meat of slaughtered eatable animals, milk products, fats, vegetables and fruits)]. The food (slaughtered cattle, eatable animals) of the people of the Scripture (Jews and Christians) is lawful to you and yours is lawful to them. (Lawful to you in marriage) are chaste women from the believers and chaste women from those who were given the Scripture (Jews and Christians) before your time when you have given their due Mahr (bridal-money given by the husband to his wife at the time of marriage), desiring chastity (i.e. taking them in legal wedlock) not committing illegal sexual intercourse, nor taking them as girlfriends”
>
> [al-Maa'idah 5:4]

This verse says that a Muslim man can marry a Jew or Christian woman.

Comment: No the verse says one is allowed to marry chaste christian or jewish women.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Technically chaste people of the scripture, I wonder if major scholars differentiate between Trinitarian christians who would likely be mushrikeen. I remember reading somewhere that the christians of tribe X are not included in the permissibility of food and marriage.

Comment: @Uma why should they differentiate if the quran already considered all of them as people of the book, calling some those whom believe among the people of the book and others those who say Allah ia three... and others those who disbelieve among people of the book. Chastity is a condition for marriage even among Muslims.